# RPC Server Is Unavailable error and Directory does not exist

Tags: c#, networking

### Background

I have written a utility that watches for files in a certain directory, and then copies them to defined target locations on remote machines. There is also a feature that allows stopping defined services in order to allow copying to the target.

In our work environment, these remote machines are typically VMs (we use VMWare Workstation) and the machines are part of a VM sub-domain, and are configured to use NAT networking (share the host machine's IP address). So when I say "remote" it's really referring to a VM running on the host.

### Problem

For my utility, I'm trying to copy files using a UNC path to the target directory, and using the machine name get a list of services using the `ServiceController.GetServices(string machineName)` method.

So if you had a VM named `server-1`, you might be trying to copy a file to `\\server-1\c$\destinationfolder`. Most of the time this works, but sometimes I see an excetion because the target directory can't be found. When this happens, we also see an error when trying to get services on the remote machine - *"The RPC server is unavailable."*

When the VM is restarted, everything works fine... for a while.

I'm having a hard time trying to nail down the issue, because it's sporadic and doesn't affect most people. I'm wondering if it's an IP issue, where VMWare changes the IP and it's stale in the host's cache? (If I sound like I don't really know what I'm talking about here, it's only because I don't... my networking knowledge is fairly basic). When I look up issues with the 'RPC server is unavailable' error, I see a lot of answers regarding firewalls, which I don't believe is the case here. We don't run anything like McAfee internally and since it works most of the time, it doesn't seem like the cause.

### Actual Questions

Anyone have any thoughts as to what might cause this problem? As a follow-up, if it is a stale IP issue, how could I recreate the issue for debugging purposes, so I can try to come up with a good way to resolve it going forward?

Comment: This sounds like a job for wireshark! It could be that your route is messed up.  I would wireshark the traffic at the source and destination to see what is happening. When the issue occurs I would also tracert to the destination IP to make sure the route is still good.  Also because of the intermittent nature of this I would look at firewall and IDS stuff to see if you are getting blocked by something.   With the wireshark trace you should be able to see if the destination machine is seeing the traffic and blocking it (rst or fin ack) or if it just all of the sudden goes silent (no ack)...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion! I know my father-in-law uses wireshark, so I will give that a shot.